# Datatypes after transformation (pyspark)still reflecting as string in azure data factory

Tags: pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have transformed the data using Azure databricks writing code in pyspark and the output is written to Azure Data lake output.csv file ...From Azure data lake it will be copied to Azure sql server ...however in Azure data factory i can see all the columns are taking as string even though during transformation i have converted the string into respective datatypes ...how do i resolve this??

PrintSchema of file in Azure databricks

[image]

In Azure datafactory mapping settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- You can continue with the copy data activity without any issue as the conversion happens automatically before data insertion.
- The following is an example of the same. I have a table with following data:

[image]

- Now, the following is the data in my csv file:

```
id,gname,sal,jd
1,Ana,100.00,2023/06/19
2,Ceb,200.00,2023/06/10
3,Topson,250.50,2023/06/05
```

- Now, when I take this csv as source and azure SQL database (SQL server table) as sink, the mapping would be similar to what you have.

[image]

- However, when I run the copy data activity, the conversion takes place automatically and the data insertion would be successful.

[image]